Maven - Generate maven-metadata.xml for each child project
Giving a maven multi-modules project, how can we run mvn deploy to generate maven-metadata.xml for each sub project and not only for the parent project ?
--> Project_A
----> project_a_1
----> project_a_2
----> project_a_2

What I'm looking for is to have the file maven-metadata.xml for each project including the parent project.
I'm using maven 3.x with java 11.

What is the use case for this?
